# How to get minimum freespace required by Android?

Tags: android, local-storage

In android, whenever we copy/write large file(s) on to internal storage we get a notification:

> Device storage is full

Although there is some **amount** of space left but still android shows the notification. I want to know how can i get programmatically get that **amount** for any android(min jellybean api 16). I need to know free space on a device excluding that **amount** of space. Devices like samsung stores that value somewhere else and i need a solution that works on all (because i have samsung and my app needs to work on other devices as well) devices.

Comment: you need to show us what you tried. did you read the documentation?

Comment: as of now i use 10% of totalspace as minimum space but i really need to know the actual value which might be less, as 10% of 64gb is 6.4gb which is waste of storage rather than reserving for other apps.